# Wrapping RefCell and Rc in a struct type

Tags: syntax, rust, traits, type-bounds

I would like to have a struct which has a writable field, but explicitly borrowable:

```
struct App<W: Clone<BorrowMut<Write>>> {
    stdout: W,
}
```

... so it can internally use it:

```
impl<W: Clone<BorrowMut<Write>>> App<W> {
    fn hello(&mut self) -> Result<()> {
        Rc::clone(&self.stdout).borrow_mut().write(b"world\n")?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

I tried to pass it a cursor and then use it:

```
let mut cursor = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Cursor::new(vec![0])));
let mut app = App { stdout: cursor };
app.hello().expect("failed to write");

let mut line = String::new();
Rc::clone(&cursor).borrow_mut().read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
```

Rust barks:

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 0, found 1
 --> src/bin/play.rs:6:21
  |
6 | struct App<W: Clone<BorrowMut<Write>>> {
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unexpected type argument
```

My end goal: pass `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` to an `App` struct. In `fn main`, these would be real stdin/stdout/stderr. In tests, these could be cursors. Since I need to access these outside of `App` (e.g. in tests), I need multiple owners (thus `Rc`) and runtime mutable borrow (thus `RefCount`).

How can I implement this?

Comment: You mean that `W` implements both `Clone` and `BorrowMut`. so `<W: Clone + BorrowMut<Write>>`

Comment: `RefCell::borrow_mut` is not related to the `BorrowMut` trait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't how you apply multiple constraints to a type parameter. Instead you use the `+` operator, like this: `<W: Clone + Write + BorrowMut>`

But, if you want `BorrowMut` to be an abstraction for `RefCell`, it won't work. The `borrow_mut` method of `RefCell` is not part of any trait so you will need to depend on `RefCell` directly in your data structure:

```
struct App<W: Clone + Write> {
    stdout: Rc<RefCell<W>>,
}
```

Having said that, it's considered best practice not to put unneeded constraints on a struct. You can actually leave them off here, and just mention them on the `impl` later.

```
struct App<W> {
    stdout: Rc<RefCell<W>>,
}
```

In order to access the contents of a `Rc`, you need to dereference with `*`. This can be a bit tricky in your case because there is a blanket  `impl` of `BorrowMut`, which means that `Rc` has a *different* `borrow_mut`, which you definitely don't want.

```
impl<W: Clone + Write> App<W> {
    fn hello(&mut self) -> Result<()> {
        (*self.stdout).borrow_mut().write(b"world\n")?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Again, when you use this, you'll need to dereference the `Rc`:

```
let cursor = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Cursor::new(vec![0])));
let mut app = App { stdout: cursor.clone() };
app.hello().expect("failed to write");

let mut line = String::new();

let mut cursor = (&*cursor).borrow_mut();
// move to the beginning or else there's nothing to read
cursor.set_position(0);
cursor.read_line(&mut line).unwrap();

println!("result = {:?}", line);
```

Also, notice that the `Rc` was cloned into the cursor. Otherwise it would be moved and you couldn't use it again later.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I also think one can remove the `+ Clone` from the W definition.